# How can I Access Tiger Sharc DSP processor through host pc?

Tags: fpga, xilinx, dsp, interface

I am working on designing of a test board which involves both FPGA(Xilinx- Kintex 7) and **DSP(Tiger Sharc)** based signal processing.

Now the **end user wants to access the DSP processor programming options/ boot configuration through the host PC itself**. As I went through the datasheets of these devices, I got the idea that I'll have to use PPLP for the communication purposes with FPGA. My question is that- **Is there any device or connector which supports communication for DSP processor with host PC** Such as PPLP to USB(- Is this a good idea to use)?

Would really appreciate if anyone has any good and concise idea about this kind of devices.

Thanks!

Comment: define PLPP? Consider PXIe, Kintex has got hardware and IP to talk to that. Use the FPGA as a bridge to the DSP.

Comment: Hmm... I am using FPGA for bridging communication with DSP.
I guess end user wants direct access of DSP IC !?
PPLP- point to point link port

Comment: One possible downside of using the FPGA to enable communication with the DSP is that you can't then use the DSP to remotely configure the FPGA, unless you play some sort of game with a bootstrap FPGA configuration or partial reconfiguration or whatever. The question is a bit short on clarity of overall system goals.

Comment: @ChrisStratton My current goal of the system design is to implement any way to directly access the  chain of DSPs from host PC apart from the FPGA since it causing a bit of delay. _I am looking for any device or IC which could drive the communication with DSPs' link port to any suitable protocol of PC_(Could be UART, USB, ethernet anything which can communicate with PC since PCs don't have link port access...)- much like FTDI2232 which drives USB to UART\FIFO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the user wants to boot the DSP as well as communicate with it, then the TigerSharc has got LinkPorts (tm), which can be used for both high speed communication, and booting.

The question is, how to connect to those to the PC. The PC doesn't have linkports, the DSP doesn't have PXIe. The obvious answer is to put whatever glue logic that's needed into the FPGA.

Presumably you have already sorted out a PC to FPGA solution? I'd be using PXIe for that, fast, universal, supported with hardware both ends and by stacks of software, long history of use. That, or ethernet, same list of benefits, but with a different flavour.

Now your task is to design an interface and API that sits in the FPGA and exposes the DSP facilities, without feeling like an FPGA to use, but instead feeling like the DSP's peripheral devices. Perhaps a bit-bang register to control any mode pins, and some dual port memory to put the boot code into.

High speed comms will depend on what the DSP is running, an RTOS, or something closer to the metal? Ideally Analog will provide drivers to make its link ports look like TCP/IP or PXIe to talk high speed comms with the PC, and you'll simply put a hub or bridge in the FPGA. If not, then you're designing a special interface.

Comment: Thank You very much!
Yes I am using ethernet for PC to FPGA. I'll be researching it further and would be doing it as you suggested in 4th paragraph.